# Finding a value written into a cell then copy the cell beside to a diferent worksheet for a range that is undefined

Tags: vba, excel

What is the best way to code a macro in VBA to find a string (that is entered on the scoring sheet) in the data sheet then copy the value to the left (on the data sheet) of the found string and paste it to the left on the scoring sheet?
I am very new to VBA and this is what I have so far, however Excel crashes when I run the code.

```
Dim x As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
NumRows = Range("C6", Range("C6").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
' Select cell a1.
Range("C6").Select
' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.   

   x = 1
   Sheets("Scoring").Select
   Do While x <= NumRows

      'Dim ws As Worksheet
      'Set ws = Worksheets("Data")

      Dim y As String
      y = Cells(5 + x, 3).Value

      Cells.Find(What:=y, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
          :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
          False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate

      Sheets("Data").Range

      Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Activate

      Selection.Resize(, Selection.Columns.Count + 0).Offset(, -1).Select
      Selection.Copy
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Selection.Copy
      Sheets("Scoring").Select
      Cells(5 + x, 2).Select
      ActiveSheet.Paste

      x = x + 1

  Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: On which line does it crash? You need to read up on how to avoid using Select/Activate, how to reference sheets, and how to use Find.

Comment: Thank you. I believe it is making excel not respond at the line: Sheets("Data").Range because its copying the whole sheet.

Comment: Ah yes, that is not correct syntax. Look up the things I mentioned - there are countless examples online - and report back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this way might give you better results:

```
Sub foo()
Dim x As Long
Dim SearchValue As String
Dim wsScore As Worksheet: Set wsScore = Sheets("Scoring")
Dim wsData As Worksheet: Set wsData = Sheets("Data")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
NumRows = wsScore.Range("C6", wsScore.Range("C6").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

For i = 6 To NumRows
    SearchValue = wsScore.Cells(i, 3).Value
    Set FoundVal = wsData.Cells.Find(What:=SearchValue, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
    :=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not FoundVal Is Nothing Then
        wsScore.Cells(i, 2).Value = FoundVal.Offset(, -1).Value
    End If
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```